# About use tf.image.crop_and_resize

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm working on the ROI pooling layer which work for fast-rcnn and I am used to use tensorflow. I found `tf.image.crop_and_resize` can act as the ROI pooling layer.

But I try many times and cannot get the result that I expected.Or did the true result is exactly what I got?

here is my code

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

img_path = r'F:\IMG_0016.JPG'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img = img.reshape([1,580,580,3])
img = img.astype(np.float32)
#img = np.concatenate([img,img],axis=0)

img_ = tf.Variable(img) # img shape is [580,580,3]
boxes = tf.Variable([[100,100,300,300],[0.5,0.1,0.9,0.5]])
box_ind = tf.Variable([0,0])
crop_size = tf.Variable([100,100])

#b = tf.image.crop_and_resize(img,[[0.5,0.1,0.9,0.5]],[0],[50,50])
c = tf.image.crop_and_resize(img_,boxes,box_ind,crop_size)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
a = c.eval(session=sess)

plt.imshow(a[0])
plt.imshow(a[1])
```

And I handed in my origin [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtX82.jpg) and result:[a0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGydi.png),[a1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjP3e.png)
if I was wrong can anyone teach me how to use this function? thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, there's no problem with Tensorflow here.

From the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize) of `tf.image.crop_and_resize` (emphasis is mine) :

> boxes: A Tensor of type float32. A 2-D tensor of shape [num_boxes, 4].
>   The i-th row of the tensor specifies the coordinates of a box in the
>   box_ind[i] image and is specified in **normalized coordinates** [y1, x1,
>   y2, x2]. A normalized coordinate value of y is mapped to the image
>   coordinate at y * (image_height - 1), so as the [0, 1] interval of
>   normalized image height is mapped to [0, image_height - 1] in image
>   height coordinates. We do allow y1 > y2, in which case the sampled
>   crop is an up-down flipped version of the original image. The width
>   dimension is treated similarly. **Normalized coordinates outside the [0,
>   1] range are allowed, in which case we use extrapolation_value to
>   extrapolate the input image values.**

The boxes argument needs normalized coordinates. That's why you get a black box with your first set of coordinates `[100,100,300,300]`  (not normalized, and no extrapolation value provided), and not with your second set `[0.5,0.1,0.9,0.5]`.

However, as that why matplotlib show you gibberish on your second attempt, it's just because you're using the wrong datatype.
Quoting the matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) of `plt.imshow` (emphasis is mine):

> All values should be in the range [0 .. 1] for floats or [0 .. 255]
>   for integers. **Out-of-range values will be clipped to these bounds**.

As you're using float outside the `[0,1]` range, matplotlib is bounding your values to `1`. That's why you get those colored pixels (either solid red, solid green  or solid blue, or a mixing of these). Cast your array to `uint_8` to get an image that make sense.

```
plt.imshow( a[1].astype(np.uint8))
```

---

**Edit :**
As requested, I will dive a bit more into
`tf.image.crop_and_resize`.

*[When providing non normalized coordinates and no extrapolation values], why I just get a blank result?*

Quoting the doc :

> Normalized coordinates outside the [0, 1] range are allowed, in which
>   case we use extrapolation_value to extrapolate the input image values.

So, normalized coordinates outside [0,1] are allowed. But they still need to be normalized ! 
With your example, `[100,100,300,300]`, the coordinates you provide makes the red square. Your original image is the little green dot in the upper left corner! The default value of the argument `extrapolation_value` is `0`, so the values outside the frame of the original image are inferred as `[0,0,0]` hence the black.
[image: crop_and_resize]

But if your usecase needs another value, you can provide it. The pixels will take a RGB value of `extrapolation_value%256` on each channel. This option is useful if the zone you need to crop is not fully included in you original images. (A possible usecase would be sliding windows for example).

Comment: Thank you ,it all worked.
But there is another question for me.As the emphasis you made in the fist quote, 'Normalized coordinates outside the [0, 1] range are allowed, in which case we use extrapolation_value to extrapolate the input image values.' What dose actually mean? Why I just get a blank result?

Comment: Check my updated answer.  If you need more information, do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: Yes,it worked.when the coordinates outside the [0, 1] range. `tf` tries to extrapolate the redundant.And what I got is the cropped Image and white area, wasn't right?Anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `tf.image.crop_and_resize` expects pixel values in the range [0,1].

Changing your code to

```
test = tf.image.crop_and_resize(image=image_np_expanded/255., ...)
```

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant is to use [tf.central_crop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/central_crop) function.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a concrete implementation of the `tf.image.crop_and_resize` API. tf version 1.14

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()

def single_data_2(img_path):
    img = tf.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_bmp(img,channels=1)
    img_4d = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    processed_img = tf.image.crop_and_resize(img_4d,boxes= 
                   [[0.4529,0.72,0.4664,0.7358]],crop_size=[64,64],box_ind=[0])
    processed_img_2 = tf.squeeze(processed_img,0)
    raw_img_3 = tf.squeeze(img_4d,0)
    return raw_img_3, processed_img_2

def plot_two_image(raw,processed):
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(35,35))
    raw_ = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
    raw_.set_title('Raw Image')
    raw_.imshow(raw,cmap='gray')
    processed_ = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
    processed_.set_title('Processed Image')
    processed_.imshow(processed,cmap='gray')

img_path = 'D:/samples/your_bmp_image.bmp'

raw_img, process_img  = single_data_2(img_path)
print(raw_img.dtype,process_img.dtype)
print(raw_img.shape,process_img.shape)
raw_img=tf.squeeze(raw_img,-1)
process_img=tf.squeeze(process_img,-1)
print(raw_img.dtype,process_img.dtype)
print(raw_img.shape,process_img.shape)
plot_two_image(raw_img,process_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my working code, also output image is not black, this can be of help to someone

```
    for idx in range(len(bboxes)):
    if bscores[idx] >= Threshold:
      #Region of Interest
      y_min = int(bboxes[idx][0] * im_height)
      x_min = int(bboxes[idx][1] * im_width)
      y_max = int(bboxes[idx][2] * im_height)
      x_max = int(bboxes[idx][3] * im_width)

      class_label = category_index[int(bclasses[idx])]['name']
      class_labels.append(class_label)
      bbox.append([x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, class_label, float(bscores[idx])])

      #Crop Image - Working Code
      cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, y_min, x_min, y_max - y_min, x_max - x_min).numpy().astype(np.int32)

      # encode_jpeg encodes a tensor of type uint8 to string
      output_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(cropped_image)
      # decode_jpeg decodes the string tensor to a tensor of type uint8
      #output_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(output_image)

      score = bscores[idx] * 100

      file_name = tf.constant(OUTPUT_PATH+image_name[:-4]+'_'+str(idx)+'_'+class_label+'_'+str(round(score))+'%'+'_'+os.path.splitext(image_name)[1])

      writefile = tf.io.write_file(file_name, output_image)
```