# Tensorflow output image is black

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning

I am using below code to crop the image, saved image is all black. How to get the correct image.

```
# Crop Image
      image_open = open(fullpath, 'rb')
      read_image = image_open.read()
      decode = tf.image.decode_jpeg(read_image)
      expand = tf.expand_dims(decode, 0)
      cropped_image = tf.image.crop_and_resize(expand, boxes=[[y_min, x_min, y_max - y_min, x_max - x_min]], crop_size=[300, 300], box_indices=[0])
      
      score = bscores[idx] * 100

      file_name = OUTPUT_PATH + image_name[:-4] + '_' + str(idx) + '_' + class_label + '_' + str(round(score)) + '%' + '_' + os.path.splitext(image_name)[1]

      #writefile = tf.io.write_file(file_name, encode)
      tf.keras.utils.save_img(file_name, np.squeeze(cropped_image)) #I am squeezing it because it is expecting 3 dim shape
```

Output Image - [image]

Comment: What happens when you run `tf.keras.utils.save_img(file_name, np.squeeze(cropped_image) / 255.)` ?

Comment: Just tried, same result with /255.

Comment: Tried with (100, 100) still same result .....tf.image.crop_and_resize(expand, boxes=[[y_min, x_min, y_max - y_min, x_max - x_min]], crop_size=[100, 100], box_indices=[0])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About use tf.image.crop\_and\_resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843509/about-use-tf-image-crop-and-resize). I.e: make sure you're using normalized coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

It is because PLT is a convenient tool you need to make it correct format and dimensions when the shape of the matrix needs to compose a picture or you do need to specify the axis.

The screen needs to match of target dimension or separate work on channels.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
CROP_SIZE = [ 210, 160 ]
OUTPUT_PATH = "F:\\temp\\20221121"

# read image and decode
fullpath = "F:\\Pictures\\actor -Kib\\272066225_493107378843948_6905696102089601304_n.jpg"
image = tf.io.read_file( fullpath )
decode = tf.image.decode_jpeg( image )
expand = tf.expand_dims(decode, 0)

# create filename and path target
filename = os.path.basename( fullpath )
image_name = str( filename.split(".")[0] ) + "." + filename.split(".")[1]
file_name_str = OUTPUT_PATH + "\\" + str( filename.split(".")[0] ) + "." + str( filename.split(".")[1] )

# crop image
boxes = tf.constant([ 0.26, 0.05, 0.8, 1.0 ], shape=(1, 4))
box_indices = tf.constant([ 0 ], shape=(1, ))
image_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array( decode )
image_cropped = tf.image.crop_and_resize( tf.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0), boxes, box_indices, CROP_SIZE )
image_cropped = tf.squeeze( image_cropped )
image_cropped = tf.keras.utils.array_to_img( image_cropped )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Output
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
plt.imshow( image_cropped )
plt.show()

# for save image
image_cropped = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array( image_cropped )
tf.keras.utils.save_img( file_name_str, tf.squeeze( image_cropped ))



input('...')
```

Save image should show up properly.

Comment: when calling this all tensor value are zeros......tf.image.crop_and_resize( tf.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0), tf.cast(boxes,dtype=tf.float32), box_indices , crop_size=[300, 300])

Comment: #This worked for me..
          y_min = int(bboxes[idx][0] * im_height)
          x_min = int(bboxes[idx][1] * im_width)
          y_max = int(bboxes[idx][2] * im_height)
          x_max = int(bboxes[idx][3] * im_width)

Comment: That is parameters see I rims it because I use it with Gym games it examines the functions. 
image_cropped = tf.image.crop_and_resize( tf.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0), boxes, box_indices, CROP_SIZE )